# What do the Icons in Kibana fields mean?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

What do the icons mean: **?**, **t**, **#**?
Noticed that I can only use fields with a **t** icon in my visualizations

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#` means it's a numeric field

`t` means it's a text field

`?` means that the type is unknown because the index patterns needs to be refreshed.

Go to Stack Management > Index patterns, pick your index pattern and click the "Refresh" button at the top right, then all your fields will be properly identified.